# VBA "With" Statement

Tags: excel, vba, variables, syntax

I have multiple variables that I want to use in one with "with" statement instead of several. Is there a way to do this? I have the snippet below, and would like to use variables a,b,c,d,e, and f

```
       With a
            .AutoFilter 1, "0"
            With a
                .clearContents
                .ClearComments
            End With
       End With
```

Comment: Store them into an array then loop through array?

Comment: Are your variables all of the same type?  It's not really clear from your posted code what the problem is, since you use `a` in both blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e` and `f` define an array and loop through

```
Dim Vars(5) As Variant 'choose your type instead of Variant

'fill your variables with content
Vars(0) = a
Vars(1) = b
' …

Dim Var As Variant 'keep this Variant
For Each Var in Vars
    With Var 
        .AutoFilter 1, "0"
        With Var 
            .clearContents
            .ClearComments
        End With
    End With
Next Var
```

Comment: Slight cringe at the `For Each` loop over an array, but it works, haha.

Comment: Cast the var to a strongly typed object so you get the intelisense working.

Comment: @BigBen Why cringe? `For Each Element In Array` doesn't sound too bad to me in a one dimensional array? `For i = LBound(Vars) To UBound(Vars)` doesn't look much better to me.

Comment: Something about `For Each` being appropriate to collections, I guess.